# Azure Storage Copy List of Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have a huge number of files, well over a million, inside an Azure blob container. It's just a single container with no directory structure. I want to copy a subset of these files, 150k or so, from the source container to a destination container. I have a list of the names of all the files I want to copy. What's the best way to do this? I prefer to use javascript or python.

I've tried `azcopy`, which allows me to move one file, or a directory of files, but not a list of file names. Doing this one file at a time is way too slow.

I've also tried looking at the documentation for the `azure-storage` javascript library, but can't seem to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: If you have a list of the names of all the files you want to copy, and do the files you want to copy have the same extension, or all the files you want to copy between a time range?

Comment: @CaptainStiggz Was the provided answer relevant to you question? If so please upvote or mark as answered to help community find relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using Azure CLI Download-batch operation, it will recursively download blobs to a specific destination of your choice:

```
az storage blob download-batch -d . --pattern *.py -s MyContainer --account-name MyStorageAccount
```

-d means destionation, . is local, More information about this option can be found [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch)

Comment: So for `pattern`, the documentation shows `[seq]` as supported. Does this mean I can supply `[file1.txt, file2.txt, ...]`? I'm trying that right now and choosing just one file is very slow.

Comment: So for pattern, you can download by extension or specific names, for example, .py would download all python files, etc

Comment: @CaptainStiggz was the above provided answer helpful to you ? 

Thanks,